# Want to get data select from database outside while loop seperated by commas

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am using jsp and mysql in my project. In this project I want to get the selected data from database after the `while()` loop seperated by commas in following way:

```
a,b,c,d,
```

The code is as follows:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    val = rs1.getString("col1");
}
```

I want all `val` values outside the loop in `a,b,c,d,` manner.

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you expand on it a bit to say more clearly what the result you want is?

Answer (score 2):

If I read you right, you could use a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(241); // Or whatever initial size you think is best

while (rs.next()) {
    sb.append(rs.getString("col1"));
    sb.append(',');
}

String val = sb.toString();
```

(I've left the trailing comma because your example *did* include it, which is somewhat unusual but simplifies things a bit.)

Answer (score 0):

```
List list = new ArrayList();
while(rs.next()){
   list.add(rs1.getString("col1"));
}
out.println( StringUtils.join(list,",");
```

Using StringUtils from commons-lang.

Comment: Please specify which libraries this solution requires.